# Getting JSON parse error using FETCH, but not when using PostMan

Tags: json, django, django-rest-framework, fetch, postman

I have set up an API endpoint using Django and django-rest-framework to submit a form using a POST request. When sending the request with PostMan, the backend works fine and adds the data to the DB. However, when I use fetch the backend returns
`{"detail":"JSON parse error - Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)"}`.
The frontend is a react webpack setup.

This is the code I am using to make the request:

```
    let csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken')

    const jsonString = JSON.stringify(data,null, '    ')
    console.log(jsonString)

    const response = await fetch(baseURL + 'jobs/',{
        method: 'POST',
        mode: 'same-origin',
        cache: 'no-cache',
        credentials: 'same-origin',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': '*/*',
            'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken,
            'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br'
        },
        body: jsonString
        });
    return response.json()
}
```

Here is the print of `jsonString`:

```
{
    "data": "asdf",
    "mode": "text",
    "node": "sdaf",
    "species": "asdf",
    "model_type": "proto",
    "dry_run": false,
    "single_fam_mode": false,
    "mail_address": ""
}
```

I also used wireshark to capture both the PostMan and the fetch request.
Here is the postman request, with the successful response:

```
[1 bytes missing in capture file].POST /api/jobs/ HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.28.3
Accept: */*
Postman-Token: 8c4b0ff0-5430-4420-8785-e965a808db5c
Host: localhost:8000
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 184

{
    "data": "asdsadad",
    "mode": "text",
    "node": "katten",
    "model_type": "both",
    "dry_run": false,
    "single_fam_mode": false,
    "mail_address": "test@teast1.no"
}HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Date: Tue, 31 Aug 2021 09:10:32 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.8.5
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept, Origin, Cookie
Allow: GET, POST, OPTIONS
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Content-Length: 271
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Referrer-Policy: same-origin

{"id": "4c6baad3-be1a-4463-8c06-edec51443565", "initiated": "2021-08-31T09:10:32.850533Z", "data": "asdsadad", "mode": "text", "species": "job@09:10:32", "node": "katten", "model_type": "both", "dry_run": false, "single_fam_mode": false, "mail_address": "test@teast1.no"}
```

Whereas this is the fetch request with the 400 response:

```
POST /api/jobs/ HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:91.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/91.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: nb-NO,nb;q=0.9,no-NO;q=0.8,no;q=0.6,nn-NO;q=0.5,nn;q=0.4,en-US;q=0.3,en;q=0.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://localhost:8000/
Content-Type: application/json
X-CSRFToken: Qv2chVzt4hiDZbe7jYDtUiP7o3IuXzVHnUUc03PYZI8FWKrOCC655rdoaThgQb1B
Origin: http://localhost:8000
Content-Length: 164
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: csrftoken=Qv2chVzt4hiDZbe7jYDtUiP7o3IuXzVHnUUc03PYZI8FWKrOCC655rdoaThgQb1B; sessionid=eqh9wotdlhh43ubszv7ievd03fnhh0fl
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin

{
    "data": "sadf",
    "mode": "text",
    "node": "asdf",
    "species": "asdf",
    "model_type": "proto",
    "dry_run": false,
    "single_fam_mode": false,
    "mail_address": ""
}HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Tue, 31 Aug 2021 10:03:05 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.8.5
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept, Origin, Cookie
Allow: GET, OPTIONS, POST
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Content-Length: 73
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Referrer-Policy: same-origin

{"detail":"JSON parse error - Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)"}
```

I haven't included any backend code as I assume it is working fine, since the postman request succeeds.

Can anyone tell me what the problem is with my fetch request?

Comment: I am not sure about fetch, but tried urllib3 and it works very fine with http request. check this reference: https://www.scrapingbee.com/blog/best-python-http-clients/

Comment: Try to also check what request.data looks like in the view

Answer (score 0):

As highlighted above, try urllib3, your code may look as follows:

```
import urllib3
import json

def get_response():
    data = {
        "data": "asdf",
        "mode": "text",
        "node": "sdaf",
        "species": "asdf",
        "model_type": "proto",
        "dry_run": False,
        "single_fam_mode": False,
        "mail_address": ""
        }

    try:

        encoded_data = json.dumps(data).encode('utf-8')
        http = urllib3.PoolManager()

        response = http.request(
            'POST',
            baseURL + 'jobs/',
            body=encoded_data,
            headers={
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': '*/*',
                'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken,
                'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br'
            }
        )
        return json.loads(response.data.decode('utf-8'))

    except:
        #Handle your error
        pass
```

Comment: Client side is react.js, not in python unfortunatelly

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you to try passing `body` without stringifying it. I am less familiar with `react.js` but in regular `ajax` requests - json passed well as-is without stringifying. I.e.:

```
const response = await fetch(baseURL + 'jobs/',{
    ...
    body: data
    });
```

Comment: Good suggestion, but when I try it, the payload is simply: [object Object] in that case

Comment: @selfjell on Django side you see [object Object]?

Comment: No, in the network inspection tab of my browser, this was all that was listed as payload for the request

Answer (score 0):

Solved!
It was actually an issue with firefox (v. 91.0.2 Mac OS X).
Once I changed to safari or the firefox developer browser it worked.
Not sure what the actual issue was though.

Comment: @EgorWexler Correct! I have a feeling there was an issue with one of my browser extensions, but I don't know the exact issue